# Is "doing" in "I'm the first woman doing it" a gerund or A participle?

Tags: present-participles, gerund-clauses

> For all the time everybody has been alive in this country, when they thought of the prime minister, they thought of a man in a suit. I’m the first woman **doing** it; I’m the first person not to be that man in that suit.

Source: [*The Washington Post*](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/lally-weymouth-interviews-australian-prime-minister-julia-gillard/2013/03/08/9d0035c0-8733-11e2-999e-5f8e0410cb9d_story.html)

> However, it is the first time ***doing*** it since James became the new Breakfast presenter on ABC Radio Sydney.

Source: [ABC News](https://www.abc.net.au/sydney/programs/weekendmornings/sunday-brunch-with-james-valentine-/101904418)

I'm the first woman **doing** it.
I'm the first woman to do it.
It is the first time ***doing*** it.

---

"***Doing***" is not a gerund or participle.
Is "**doing**" also not a gerund or participle? What do you say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern grammars don't distinguish between gerunds and participles, and nor should you.

So you can say this is a gerund-participle.

Traditional grammars distinguish between -ing verbs which are in a position in which a noun phrase would be possible and -ing verbs in other positions.  In  this case "doing it" is  not in a position in which a noun phrase is possible, hence a "participle".